# How to get a message from compiler when incorrect string format is used

Tags: string, delphi, formatting

Here is a piece of Delphi code that the compiler perfectly compiles :

```
Var S: String;

Begin
 S := Format('%s  %s', ['Hello']);
....
```

But on execution it raises an exception, of course there are two argument in the left string, and only one in the brackets...

Is there a way to have this error checked by the compiler and to be displayed at least as a warning, or better fatal error?

Comment: FixInsight is the tool you are looking for

Comment: I just see it now.
Thanks a lot for this info, I'll try it out asap.

Comment: Just tried, and detected the issue I have posted above. But, if this is written

 f:=20.233; // is a double
 S:=Format('%s  %d',['hello',f]);

Does not detect any issue. Yes I'm a pain in the n... but for 100$ this software it shoukd detect this.

Comment: Submit a bug report. The tool is actively developed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler as currently written makes no effort to know about what's embedded between the quotes in the first parameter. It also doesn't count the values being passed in the second parameter, or have any idea whether they're correct. They're not evaluated until the function is called, where the exception is raised because they're incorrect. IOW, the compiler does not attempt to do anything that would allow it to issue such a warning or error.

When the function is called at runtime, it validates the number of arguments, whether they're the right type or not, and whether you've provided proper arguments. The compiler doesn't attempt to do that in any way. It only makes sure that you provide a string for the first parameter and an array of const for the second.

So to directly answer the question you've asked: No, there is no way to have the error checked by the compiler to have it issue a warning, because the compiler makes no effort to check anything that would allow it to do so.

Comment: OK, is there a tool that can parse the code and at least help out to find some silly error like this one above ?

Comment: "*IOW, the information is not available at compile time in order for the compiler to give you that message*" - well, the information is *available*, but the compiler simply ignores it. Modern C++ compilers are able to validate `printf`/`scanf` style parameters at compile-time (ie via `__attribute__((__format__ (...)))` in gcc/clang). The Delphi compiler *could* be updated to recognize `Format()` for special processing (maybe flag it with a compile-time attribute) and *parse* the string in the 1st param to compare it with the array values in the 2nd param. They just haven't implemented that yet

Comment: @RemyLebeau: And it's highly unlikely that they'll update the compiler to do that any time in the forseeable future. The current compiler does not implement that functionality.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm aware that the *current* compiler doesn't implement this. I'm just saying that a *future* compiler *could* support it, if someone were to submit a feature request to QualityPortal and it got enough votes.

Comment: @KenWhite "*There's no way to evaluate those arguments for validity without calling the function, period*" - this is something an external static analysis tool could easily parse. Whether any existing analysis tools support this particular check is another matter...

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Edited post. Removed comment that seemed to bother you. I highly doubt that enough people would upvote such a suggestion to give it priority over the many other things that should be addressed in the compiler.

Comment: If a variable is passed for the format string, or where part of the parameter is a variable, the compiler couldn't be able to parse. In which case I'd rather have no parsing at no condition,

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Agreed. I've never had the desire for the compiler to do validations for format, myself. I'd rather have work done in other areas of the compiler instead.

Comment: @Sertac A non const format string is itself asking for trouble, and seldom used. So I don't think that's a great argument.

Comment: @David - In that case I want to bring forward resource strings, which I use quite some with Format, which the compiler shouldn't even attempt to parse because the source module can change without compiling. Even if that's still not OK, I dislike the idea that the compiler being able to do things at times. But that's my opinion of course.

Comment: This is a CONSTANT string i'm speaking about. Can't the compiler recognize this ? I can do it with my own eyes (but not 100% of the time :-)

Comment: It would be possible for the compiler to validate these parameters if the format string is a regular string constant. For applications that must be internationalized, this will never be the case. The will either use ressource strings or something like the _() function in GnuGettext.

Comment: In addition to that shortcoming there is no way to specify in a format string "allow anything that can be converted to a string" even though the runtime code knows wich kind of parameter was passed (there was a QC entry for that but it was ignored for years and is now gone with QC). If you specify %s your parameter must be a string, if you specify %f your parameter must be a floating point value (and cannot even be an integer IIRC). You get less than optimal runtime errors in these cases.

Comment: I agree that `Format` is very often used with `resourcestring`s. In fact, the vast majority of my `Format`s are called with a `resourcestring` as the first argument. Still, even in this case, the compiler could (in theory) verify that the value given to the `resourcestring` in the source code matches the list of parameters. Then my translation tool could warn me about inconsistencies between different languages.

Comment: This is in the end sily that an expection is raised for that .. and if not trapped, just ruins all...

Comment: @user1816813: So complain to EMBT. We can't change that here. Your question has been answered here.

Comment: @user1816813: I'm not being aggressive. It's an issue of you continuing to post comments to this answer, which keep appearing in my notifications, which means all of your complaints (that I can do nothing about) are getting annoying. If you have a different question about C#, then click the *Ask Question* button at the top of the page and ask it. I can do nothing about how Delphi's compiler is implemented internally, and I can do nothing to make you feel better about it. :-) I've answered the question you asked, which is all I can do to help.

Comment: Ken, thanks. Are you 100% sure of your reply ? Do you know delphi to the last corner ?

Comment: This is not a disrespectful comment, just to be sure, of course I found the reply perfectly logic and meanningfull in the end. I have 4200 format() calls into my 1 million line code, and Delphi editor is full of corners... Now I have no other solution than making my own piece of software to parse all the format() thru my code and try to check for any oddities like I wrote on top of the post. It would be great EMB to take into consideration this.

Comment: You don't have to rely on static checking. Your unit testing and integration testing can resolve rhis. After all, you need to have this because there are errors which can't be detected by static analysis. Perhaps your real problem is writing a million lines of code without corresponding tests.